# Using Docker with Jenkins to spin off slave containers

Tags: docker, jenkins, devops, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-agent

So I've been trying to follow the riot games tutorial on setting up jenkins with docker to spin off ephemeral containers. https://engineering.riotgames.com/news/jenkins-ephemeral-docker-tutorial

The thing is this uses the deprecated docker toolbox and I'm setting this up natively on a CentOS box. The issue I'm running into is trying to get the slave and master containers to communicate.

By that I mean I cannot find the hostIP of docker to open it up, I cannot find the docker.conf or related to files to actually open anything up, dockerd -H hangs when trying to open up the unix socket, and trying to open 0.0.0.0:2375 seems very unsafe though it has been recommended on several other tutorials. I'm trying to use the docker plugin and when going to the "cloud" portion of the configuration is where I get confused.

All in all I'm just confused on the next steps, I've set up my dockerfiles, docker compose, etc but I'm not sure how to get the communication to work and make it work safely. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the [JClouds Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/JClouds+Plugin) installed as well? It looks like this is needed to complete the cloud portion of the tutorial you linked to

Comment: I do. Really the portion I get tripped on is opening/forcing the secure port open and how to generate the keys/certs on a baremetal centos machine and using those to get the docker container jenkins slaves to communicate back to the host.